# iOS Google Signin SDK webview not closing after signin

Tags: ios, webview, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I am using the iOS Google Signin SDK. I did that by following the tutorial here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in

When I click on the Google Signin button, the webview appears and then when I login through Google, the signin method delegate

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
 withError:(NSError *)error;
```

is called. The user is logged in.

I also have the appDelegate openURL method called. But, the webview does not close by itself and I need to click on 'Ok' to close it.

Does someone get something like that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are setting your UI delegate like so –

`[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;`

You also need to implement –

`- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn 
dismissViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`

Inside that function you need to dismiss the Google view controller by calling `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: Thank you for that!
I do not understand how you dismiss the googe view controller. I do not keep a pointer to the view controller so calling 
  `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` will only close the view controller from where I call the function.

Comment: I finally added
`-(void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn dismissViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
`